# What is the song playing in My Hero Academia season 2 episode 25 at 10:00?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

In *My Hero Academia* season 2 episode 25, there's a song playing at the 10:00 mark.

What is the name of the song? Starting to think it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The OST is : **Tsune ni Top wo Nerau Mono**

Check this link at 0:50  : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54ls1DUVjRg

Answer (score 0):

The OST is Hard Time
The link is: https://open.spotify.com/track/7Kod41bdquBmoYgl0voVul?si=K0qBC2Y-TomLILHXNa_96Q